# Meaning of Multiplicative Group to the power n i.e. Z^n

Tags: group-theory, notation

What does $Z_q^n$ mean in this notation?
    [image]

References:  on the 2nd paragraph of page:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_with_errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means vectors of dimension $n$, where each entry is in $\mathbb{Z}_q$. I.e., $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ means that $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

Comment: Here q is prime? i guess.

Comment: It really doesnt have to be. In general the notation $S^n$, for some set $S$, means the set of n-dimensional vectors with entries in $S$.